# Difference between pip install options "ignore-installed" and "force-reinstall"

Tags: python, pip, pypi

There are two `pip install` options related to reinstalling the packages, which are `--ignore-installed` and `--force-reinstall`.

These two options described as following in the official doc

```
--force-reinstall
Reinstall all packages even if they are already up-to-date.

-I, --ignore-installed
Ignore the installed packages (reinstalling instead).
```

It seems that they all ignore something and do the reinstallation but I cannot tell the difference between them (I can see some difference if I actually execute them ... but I cannot explain). If I search "force reinstall packages in pip", the result lists both `--ignore-installed` and `--force-reinstall`, which confuses me for a long time.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

#### `--force-reinstall`

Before installing a package, will uninstall it first if already installed. Pretty much the same as running `pip uninstall -y dep && pip install dep` for package and its every dependency.

#### `--ignore-installed`

Ignores whether the package and its deps are already installed, overwriting installed files. This means that you can have a situation where `--ignore-installed` does not uninstall a file, leaving it in `site-packages` forever. Imagine you have `pkgname==1.0` that provides module `spam`:

```
$ pip show -f pkgname
Name: pkgname
Version: 1.0
...
spam.py
```

and the next version `pkgname==2.0` renamed `spam` to `eggs`. When running `pip install pkgname==2.0 --ignore-installed`, `spam.py` will not be removed, left orphaned forever until you remove it manually.

#### Consequence

`--force-reinstall` should always be preferred; use `--ignore-installed` only if you <s>know what you're doing</s> are sure that the reinstall will overwrite currently installed files. Otherwise, you may get obscure import errors after reinstall due to stale modules still available in `sys.path`.

#### Example

Example to reproduce with the latest `pip` changes where all its packages were moved under `_internal` package: create a new virtual environment and downgrade `pip` to version 9:

```
$ mkvirtualenv testenv
$ workon testenv
(testenv) $ pip install "pip<10"
```

If you would now upgrade `pip` to the latest version via `--force-reinstall`, a clean upgrade is performed. Afterwards, you have the correct package structure with the `_internal` and `_vendor`:

```
(testenv) $ pip install pip --upgrade --force-reinstall
(testenv) $ ls -l $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
total 16
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff   21 19 Aug 11:47 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  623 19 Aug 11:47 __main__.py
drwxr-xr-x   4 hoefling  staff  128 19 Aug 11:47 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  25 hoefling  staff  800 19 Aug 11:47 _internal
drwxr-xr-x  26 hoefling  staff  832 19 Aug 11:47 _vendor
```

If you would do the upgrade with `--ignore-installed` instead:

```
(testenv) $ pip install pip --upgrade --ignore-installed
(testenv) $ ls -l $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
total 392
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff     21 19 Aug 12:33 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff    623 19 Aug 12:33 __main__.py
drwxr-xr-x  14 hoefling  staff    448 19 Aug 12:33 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  25 hoefling  staff    800 19 Aug 12:33 _internal
drwxr-xr-x  28 hoefling  staff    896 19 Aug 12:33 _vendor
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  11910 19 Aug 12:33 basecommand.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  10465 19 Aug 12:33 baseparser.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  16474 19 Aug 12:33 cmdoptions.py
drwxr-xr-x  16 hoefling  staff    512 19 Aug 12:33 commands
drwxr-xr-x   5 hoefling  staff    160 19 Aug 12:33 compat
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  32153 19 Aug 12:33 download.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff   8121 19 Aug 12:33 exceptions.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  39950 19 Aug 12:33 index.py
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff   5626 19 Aug 12:33 locations.py
drwxr-xr-x   5 hoefling  staff    160 19 Aug 12:33 models
drwxr-xr-x   6 hoefling  staff    192 19 Aug 12:33 operations
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  10980 19 Aug 12:33 pep425tags.py
drwxr-xr-x   8 hoefling  staff    256 19 Aug 12:33 req
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff    156 19 Aug 12:33 status_codes.py
drwxr-xr-x  16 hoefling  staff    512 19 Aug 12:33 utils
drwxr-xr-x   8 hoefling  staff    256 19 Aug 12:33 vcs
-rw-r--r--   1 hoefling  staff  32010 19 Aug 12:33 wheel.py
```

Upgrading `pip` with `--ignore-installed` did not uninstall previous package version first, and due to new file structure, new files did not overwrite the old ones. As a consequence, old files are now orphaned and not picked up by any package; even `pip uninstall pip` will not remove the orphaned files. One would need to clean them up manually.

Comment: Is `--upgrade` flag is needed with `--force-reinstall`?

Comment: @mrgloom no, you can safely omit that. `--force-reinstall` implies `--upgrade` same way as a `pip uninstall` followed by a `pip install` would do (the newest version matching the specifier is found and installed).

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I find more simple and mnemonic to do `pip uninstall package && pip install package` :-D

Answer (score 11):

--ignore-installed can also be used if you have a virtual env that inherits the global site-package and you want to override the global installation (without uninstalling it).
**For example you can have version N in the global python installation and version N+1 in the venv.**
It is very convenient to test/debug a new version of a package in a virtual env.

Comment: Good point, this also applies to user installs (`pip install --user`) when in need of overriding system installation of a package.

Comment: For me, `--ignore-installed` has also been very useful when I got problems when pip wanted to uninstall and reinstall a dependency because it couldn't delete the `__pycache__` dirs (happened to me in a Docker environment in a CentOS 7 host, weird filesystem bug)